# jqPlot meter gauge in drupal

Tags: javascript, html, drupal, jqplot

Im try to add meter gauge to my site, I added the js and the css to my info file

than in the page I have this code

```
    <script>$(document).ready(function(){
   s1 = [1];

   plot0 = $.jqplot('chart0',[s1],{
       title: 'Network Speed',
       seriesDefaults: {
           renderer: $.jqplot.MeterGaugeRenderer,
           rendererOptions: {
               label: 'MB/s'
           }
       }
   });
});
</script>
<div class="plot0" style="width:250px;height:170px;"></div>
```

It give me an error "Uncaught No plot target specified ", any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach an id to your container :

```
<div id="chart0" class="plot0" style="width:250px;height:170px;"></div>
```

And then to use this id to plot your chart

Please see a working example [here on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/3EDH2/)

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  Unfortunately, this example is not working for me.  Nothing renders.  Any ideas?